# dygraphs smooth lines with drawPoints

Tags: lines, dygraphs, smoothing

I used this exmaple http://dygraphs.com/tests/smooth-plots.html to draw smooth lines. When I anable the smoothing by `plotter: smoothPlotter` small dots at data points disappear. I have set `drawPoints: true`. Dot is displayed when mouse is on the curve.

How can I enable small dots at data points ( http://dygraphs.com/options.html#drawPoints ) and still use smoothing?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to enable pointdrawing. But you can make a second series with the same data and draw only the points, not the lines. Like so:

```
    new Dygraph(document.getElementById('graph'),
            functionData,
            {
series: {
  Straight: {
    color: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    drawPoints: true,
    pointSize: 7
  },
  Smoothed: {
    plotter: smoothPlotter,
    color: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 2
  }
},
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLxs4ju1/

Comment: Maybe the smoothPlotter need to be modified to enable the  pointdrawing without adding new series.

Comment: I think the problem is, that smoothgraph will draw thousands of points to show the smooth lines. Therefor they disregard the drawPoints attribute in the config.